# Using -ている form in the past tense

Tags: て-form, tense, aspect

What's the difference between

> きのう、いちじかんほんをよみました。

and

> きのう、いちじかんほんをよんでいました。

?

What would be the equivalent English translations for the two sentences?

Answer (score 1):

With action verbs like 読む{よむ} the -ている　form becomes -ing in English.

> 昨日{きのう}、一{いち}時間{じかん}本{ほん}を読み{よみ}ました。
>   I read a book for one hour yesterday.
>   昨日{きのう}、一{いち}時間{じかん}本{ほん}を読{よ}んでいました。
>   I was reading a book for one hour yesterday.

Comment: Is it just me or would 一時間本を読みました sound a little odd? I feel like if you specify a period of time that you should probably use ～ていた instead of ～た.

Comment: @sazarando Both sentences sound just fine to me.

Comment: @sazarando If you focus a point in time, past progressive form is appropriate like あなたが電話をくれたとき、私はお風呂に入っていました( I was taking a bath when you called me.). If not, I think both are used as same meaning.

Comment: (Excuse me if this is a dumb question but) what's the difference of "read a book for one hour yesterday" and "was reading a book for one hour yesterday"?

Comment: @chocolate Excellent question. Without any further context both sound identical to me. If I think harder, maybe "was reading a book" sounds more like you are re-living the moment, whereas "read a book" is just a plain, boring statement of fact. How do you think they differ in Japanese?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In Japanese, 「昨日は、一時間本を読みました」 sounds a bit more natural to me. With 読んでいました, I think we usually say like「昨日は**５**時間(も)本を読んでいました」 etc. with a nuance of "for such long hours" or "spent the (whole) day reading".